# Bathtub door installation when bathtub has raised rim

Tags: doors, shower, bathtub

I live in a newly built condo where the bathtub was not framed properly in the sense that where the tub meets the wall, it is flushed or have a 90 degree angle. In other words, there is tiny raised edge on the rim of the bathtub, similar to a small floor molding on a hardwood floor, if you can imagine that.
I was recently gifted with a frame-less "fixed pane" for a shower door.
This glass pane is tempered, of course, which makes any cutting or alternation impossible.

Does anyone have a solution, or am I doomed to use a shower curtain forever?

[image: Raised edge of rim of bathtub]

Comment: Tub is installed the way it was made to be installed. "Not framed properly" is an incorrect assessment.

Comment: diamond blade will cut it

Comment: What material is the tub?

Comment: I don't know what the tub material is. I had thought of cutting through it if it is soft enough, but given the fact that the tub is already installed, I will most likely create a very messy job.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly how much that lip protrudes from the wall but it looks in the picture like it's small enough that you could work around it.  Use standoffs the same thickness as the lip to install the door brackets to the wall, and fill the gap between glass and tile with silicone.

You can make it stronger, and look great by buying or making large rectangular standoffs that match the color and shape of the brackets where they meet the wall, more like shims than standoffs.  And by using clear silicone to fill the gap.

I hope there is a stud or blocking behind the tile there!  Don't mount a frameless panel to the tile/backerboard.  Use screws that are suitably longer to compensate for the standoffs.

Comment: Thank you jay613. I had thought of using standoffs or spacers, but the gap is about 1/2 inch, making the use of silicone to fill the gap a rather messy job in the end, given that I will be attempting to fill a gap that is 55 inches long.

Comment: Then use a [frameless shower side seal](https://www.amazon.com/AmazerBath-Frameless-Section-Segmented-Installation/dp/B0BM46KV4K/ref=mp_s_a_1_6_sspa).   Extends 3/4".

Comment: LOL. Thank you, jay613. I was thinking the exact same thing last night when I was going over what other possibilities I could try, and I went on Amazon trying to locate something similar, but you found a much better product. Fingers crossed here, hoping it will work. Thank you a million, jay613!

Answer (score 0):

The tub is installed correctly.  Your problem is that you were gifted a glass door that is not suitable for your tub situation.

Donate the door to someone else.  Call people that specialize in glass tub and shower enclosures.